# Decryption using python gnupg

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cryptography, gnupg

I am deploying a code to AWS elastic beanstalk where a celery worker tries to decrypt a pgp encrypted file. This is my code.

```
import gnupg
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
key_data = open('/home/ec2-user/key-secret.asc').read()
import_result = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
file_input = open('input_file', 'rb')
ob = gpg.decrypt_file(file_input, passphrase='secret_password', output='/tmp/temp.zip')
```

Whenever this worker is running, the file is not getting decrypted and I am getting 'gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error' on ob.stderr

However when I ssh into the system and manually type and run the above code in python shell, everything works just fine. Can someone point me the issue here ?

Comment: Ever get this one figured out? We're running into a very similar issue.